# MessagePack : MessageTypeException: Expected raw value, but got boolean [Android]

Tags: android, serialization, deserialization, msgpack

I am implementing MessagePack in my android application. I am getting following error while deserializing Response data only when app runs in below API 22 devices;

```
Caused by: org.msgpack.MessageTypeException: Expected raw value, but got boolean
at org.msgpack.unpacker.Accept.acceptBoolean(Accept.java:33)
at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readOneWithoutStackLarge(MessagePackUnpacker.java:154)
at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readOneWithoutStack(MessagePackUnpacker.java:139)
at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readOne(MessagePackUnpacker.java:73)
at org.msgpack.unpacker.MessagePackUnpacker.readString(MessagePackUnpacker.java:472)
at org.msgpack.template.StringTemplate.read(StringTemplate.java:46)
at org.msgpack.template.StringTemplate.read(StringTemplate.java:25)
at org.msgpack.template.builder.ReflectionTemplateBuilder$FieldTemplateImpl.read(ReflectionTemplateBuilder.java:70)
at org.msgpack.template.builder.ReflectionTemplateBuilder$ReflectionClassTemplate.read(ReflectionTemplateBuilder.java:143)
```

If I run same application in device with API 22 or above everything works fine.

Following code is for deserialize ;

```
private T readMessagePack(byte[] response, Class<T> responseType) throws Exception
    {        
        MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();
        TemplateRegistry registry = new TemplateRegistry(null);
        ReflectionTemplateBuilder builder = new ReflectionTemplateBuilder(registry);
        Template<T> objTemplate = builder.buildTemplate(responseType);
        BufferUnpacker unpacker = msgpack.createBufferUnpacker();
        unpacker.resetReadByteCount();
        unpacker.wrap(response);
        return objTemplate.read(unpacker, null);

    }
```

I am using `org.msgpack:msgpack:0.6.8` Dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing research I solved my issue. May be my answer will helpful to someone.

This issue is caused by the order of declared fields that BufferUnpacker returns. For that we have to use `@Index()` annotation while Serializing & Deserializing.
For example;

```
@Index(0)
    public boolean state;
@Index(1)
    public String error_message;
```